# App doesn't update on physical device when debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Even after changing the source code, the application doesn't update when debugging on the physical device and keeps debugging the old code.

Issue log:

```
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of crash
--------- beginning of main
2022-08-19 23:38:10.699 11917-11917 studio.deploy           pid-11917                            E  Could not get package user id: run-as: unknown package: com.example.todo
2022-08-19 23:38:10.732 11917-11917 studio.deploy           pid-11917                            E  Could not find apks for this package: com.example.todo
2022-08-19 23:38:10.983 11917-11917 studio.deploy           pid-11917                            E  Could not get package user id: run-as: unknown package: com.example.todo
2022-08-19 23:38:11.012 11917-11917 studio.deploy           pid-11917                            E  Could not find apks for this package: com.example.todo
2022-08-19 23:38:14.015  1323-1732  VerityUtils             system_server                        E  Failed to measure fs-verity, errno 1: /data/app/~~0IRjR1rweYuG9z-ALmLwhg==/com.example.todo-th6zW0_OOBa1h4_gTqo8xA==/base.apk
2022-08-19 23:38:19.518  6371-6371  FinalizerDaemon         com.example.todo                     W  type=1400 audit(0.0:539): avc: denied { getopt } for path="/dev/socket/usap_pool_primary" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c228,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:zygote:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0 app=com.example.todo
2022-08-19 23:38:20.727  6371-12107 ProfileInstaller        com.example.todo                     D  Installing profile for com.example.todo
2022-08-19 23:39:52.416  6371-12095 AdrenoGLES-0            com.example.todo                     I  QUALCOMM build                   : 03dd3ba, I13854cb805
                                                                                                    Build Date                       : 10/28/20
                                                                                                    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.32.02.02
                                                                                                    Local Branch                     : mybrancheb191cbf-5661-f183-9b13-08f1eafda2d8
                                                                                                    Remote Branch                    : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r122-rel
                                                                                                    Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                                                    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2022-08-19 23:39:52.416  6371-12095 AdrenoGLES-0            com.example.todo                     I  Build Config                     : S L 10.0.7 AArch64
2022-08-19 23:39:52.416  6371-12095 AdrenoGLES-0            com.example.todo                     I  Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
2022-08-19 23:39:52.559  6371-12095 AdrenoGLES-0            com.example.todo                     I  PFP: 0x005ff114, ME: 0x005ff066
2022-08-19 23:39:52.656  6371-12304 Gralloc4                com.example.todo                     I  mapper 4.x is not supported
2022-08-19 23:39:52.657  6371-12304 Gralloc3                com.example.todo                     W  mapper 3.x is not supported
2022-08-19 23:39:52.667  6371-12304 Gralloc4                com.example.todo                     W  allocator 4.x is not supported
2022-08-19 23:39:52.669  6371-12304 Gralloc3                com.example.todo                     W  allocator 3.x is not supported
2022-08-19 23:39:52.670  6371-12304 Gralloc2                com.example.todo                     I  Adding additional valid usage bits: 0x202000
2022-08-19 23:40:50.311  6371-12075 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.todo                     I  Davey! duration=57938ms; Flags=1, FrameTimelineVsyncId=67044, IntendedVsync=1453350490076, Vsync=1453350490076, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=1453351074027, AnimationStart=1453351075277, PerformTraversalsStart=1453369889757, DrawStart=1453726480121, FrameDeadline=1453383823408, FrameInterval=1453351071111, FrameStartTime=16666666, SyncQueued=1453736846892, SyncStart=1453736997829, IssueDrawCommandsStart=1453737964392, SwapBuffers=1453826903715, FrameCompleted=1511288907912, DequeueBufferDuration=8409896, QueueBufferDuration=1729635, GpuCompleted=1511288907912, SwapBuffersCompleted=1453830047308, DisplayPresentTime=0, 
2022-08-19 23:40:50.311  6371-12075 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.todo                     I  Davey! duration=57911ms; Flags=0, FrameTimelineVsyncId=67050, IntendedVsync=1453383994037, Vsync=1453833994019, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=1453836806215, AnimationStart=1453836807829, PerformTraversalsStart=1453836808715, DrawStart=1453836947361, FrameDeadline=1453433994035, FrameInterval=1453836802621, FrameStartTime=16666666, SyncQueued=1453838596058, SyncStart=1453838659236, IssueDrawCommandsStart=1453838739548, SwapBuffers=1453840537361, FrameCompleted=1511295465203, DequeueBufferDuration=24271, QueueBufferDuration=1600104, GpuCompleted=1511295465203, SwapBuffersCompleted=1453843213246, DisplayPresentTime=0, 
2022-08-19 23:40:56.579 12334-12334 studio.deploy           install_server-7271c3ba              E  Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.todo/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory
2022-08-19 23:40:57.388  6372-6372  GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.todo                     V  ANGLE Developer option for 'com.example.todo' set to: 'default'
2022-08-19 23:40:57.389  6372-6372  GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.todo                     V  ANGLE GameManagerService for com.example.todo: false
2022-08-19 23:40:57.389  6372-6372  GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.todo                     V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
2022-08-19 23:40:57.390  6372-6372  NetworkSecurityConfig   com.example.todo                     D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-08-19 23:40:57.390  6372-6372  NetworkSecurityConfig   com.example.todo                     D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-08-19 23:40:57.446  6372-6372  om.example.tod          com.example.todo                     E  Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2022-08-19 23:40:58.100  6372-12467 AdrenoGLES-0            com.example.todo                     I  QUALCOMM build                   : 03dd3ba, I13854cb805
                                                                                                    Build Date                       : 10/28/20
                                                                                                    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.32.02.02
                                                                                                    Local Branch                     : mybrancheb191cbf-5661-f183-9b13-08f1eafda2d8
                                                                                                    Remote Branch                    : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r122-rel
                                                                                                    Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                                                    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2022-08-19 23:40:58.100  6372-12467 AdrenoGLES-0            com.example.todo                     I  Build Config                     : S L 10.0.7 AArch64
2022-08-19 23:40:58.100  6372-12467 AdrenoGLES-0            com.example.todo                     I  Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
2022-08-19 23:40:58.111  6372-12467 AdrenoGLES-0            com.example.todo                     I  PFP: 0x005ff114, ME: 0x005ff066
2022-08-19 23:40:58.127  6372-12470 Gralloc4                com.example.todo                     I  mapper 4.x is not supported
2022-08-19 23:40:58.127  6372-12470 Gralloc3                com.example.todo                     W  mapper 3.x is not supported
2022-08-19 23:40:58.129  6372-12470 Gralloc4                com.example.todo                     W  allocator 4.x is not supported
2022-08-19 23:40:58.129  6372-12470 Gralloc3                com.example.todo                     W  allocator 3.x is not supported
2022-08-19 23:40:58.130  6372-12470 Gralloc2                com.example.todo                     I  Adding additional valid usage bits: 0x202000
2022-08-19 23:40:58.154  6372-12462 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.todo                     I  Davey! duration=745ms; Flags=1, FrameTimelineVsyncId=71281, IntendedVsync=1518473511057, Vsync=1518606844385, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=1518621310982, AnimationStart=1518621312752, PerformTraversalsStart=1518621542492, DrawStart=1519200839992, FrameDeadline=1518490177723, FrameInterval=1518621303117, FrameStartTime=16666666, SyncQueued=1519208728690, SyncStart=1519208842388, IssueDrawCommandsStart=1519209258221, SwapBuffers=1519217145096, FrameCompleted=1519219182961, DequeueBufferDuration=22916, QueueBufferDuration=811250, GpuCompleted=1519218461971, SwapBuffersCompleted=1519219182961, DisplayPresentTime=0, 
2022-08-19 23:40:58.231  6372-6372  Choreographer           com.example.todo                     I  Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2022-08-19 23:41:03.178  6372-12482 ProfileInstaller        com.example.todo                     D  Installing profile for com.example.todo
2022-08-19 23:41:15.247  6372-6372  FinalizerDaemon         com.example.todo                     W  type=1400 audit(0.0:542): avc: denied { getopt } for path="/dev/socket/usap_pool_primary" scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c228,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:zygote:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0 app=com.example.todo
2022-08-19 23:41:15.249  6372-12459 System                  com.example.todo                     W  A resource failed to call close.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: I've added the full log for better understanding.

Comment: Note: I recently updated from 11 to 12L, this issue wasn't present then.

Comment: Full log added.

Answer (score 0):

After spending all night yesterday I found that This issue is very firmware specific. This issue came with the custom rom I recently installed, and it is solvable by installing a different rom.

Note: This answer doesn't say how to solve this issue (i.e how to fix the rom), just a possible case that can make such an issue and bypass it all together (should be helpful for newcomers).